# How to run botium tests in vs code with javascript,mocha and jasmine

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

I want to setup botium with vs code IDE .I need guidance for this.
As botium is brand new.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation: create a project directory, and start VSCode to open this project directory (File -> Open Folder ...). Then open terminal window (Terminal -> New Terminal ...) and enter initialization commands:

```
npm init -y
npm install --save botium-cli
botium-cli init
```

To run the test cases:

```
botium-cli run
```

These are the first step to set up a Botium project.

Next steps:
- adapt botium.json to connect to your chatbot
- write convo files

Comment: Botium-cli not installing .I'm getting the below error

Comment: npm WARN deprecated watson-developer-cloud@3.18.4: DeprecationWarning: watson-developer-cloud moved to ibm-watson. To get updates, use the
new package.
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/codeforequity-at/jsonpath.git
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-27T10_40_26_949Z-debug.log

Comment: Pls install a git client first, or instead of using NPM to install botium-cli, you can download a precompiled botium-cli https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-cli#download-latest-executable-standalone-program-from-here